# is it invalid to set a reference to null or 0?

Tags: sql, mysql, t-sql, foreign-keys

I'll be doing this in sqlite now that they support foreign keys and tsql and perhaps mysql.

Is it illegal to do something like

```
CREATE TABLE comment(
id integer primary key,
parent integer references(comment.id),
author integer references(User.id),
desc varchar(max),
hidden  bit
deleted bit
);
```

where parent may be 0 or null because it is the root and does not have a parent? AFAIK i wont be deleting any comments but will set it to hidden or as `deleted`. I mostly want to know if i can have the root as 0 or null otherwise i have no idea how i can have the comment have a reference a parent (i cant make the first one point to itself?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a column with a FOREIGN KEY can be nullable, but it can't hold a '0' if there's no corresponding row in the parent table with a '0' in it.  '0' is a value whereas NULL represents "no value".

So in this case the root nodes of the "adjacency list" structure you're setting up will have NULL for the value of "parent".